# Google cloud workflow to call API and load response json to GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am trying to use GCP workflow to call API and load the response into GCS bucket. I have used as per example but I am unable to load the json response to gcs bucket.
Please suggest.

```
main:
    params: [input]
    steps:
    - checkInput:
        swicth:
            - condition: ${"searchterm" in input}
              assign:
                - searchTerm: ${input.searchTerm}
              next: readwikipedia
    - getcurrenttime:
        call: http.get
        args:
            url: https://us-central-workflowsample.cloudfunctions.net/datetime
        result: currentDate
    - setFromcallResult:
        assign:
            - searchTerm: ${currentDate.body.dayOfTheWeek}
    - readWiki:
        call: http:get
        args:
            url: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
            query:
                action: opensearch
                search:${searchTerm}
        result: wikiResult
    - returoOutput:
        return: ${wikiResult.body[1]}
    - load_gcs
        call: googleapis.storage.v1.objects.insert
        args:
            bucket: "test_buck"
            uploadType: "media"
            name: "sample.json"
        body: ${wikiResult.body[1]}
```

Comment: Do you have any error? log trave?

Comment: No error in workflow log but can't upload the json file

Comment: "can't" means something block. Do you simply have nothing in storage and the workflow end in success?

Comment: Thats right.Workflow executed successfully but nothing in the bucket.

Comment: Catch the result of the insert step and log it. In fact, either it works or it fails. Black hole is not an option!!

Comment: I'd also check the idention of "body" in "load_gcs".  I think it should be inside "args"

Answer (score 0):

The following code is ending your workflow:

```
- returoOutput:
    return: ${wikiResult.body[1]}
```

So it never reaches the step 'load_gcs'. Try to put that step to the end.